# How can I do pattern matching for the below text using c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, string-function

```
String text = "time : 11/22/2019 10:22:22 AM Message: db connection failed. Catergory: debug Priority: 2 EventId: 5 process Id: 12 process name: exe.win32"
```

How can I do the pattern matching and separate the specific fields and extract the data?

Comment: Please read up on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . What have you tried and where do you fail? Do you want all fields or just specific ones? Are these texts always of the exact same format with all fields present?

Comment: If you use a structured logging framework you may not have the problem of writing a log parser

Comment: It would be a *lot* easier if the message didn't use whitespace as a field separator. Assuming `;` as the separator, a regex like `(?<name>.*?):(?<value>.*?);` could capture all key value pairs. A JSON string would be even better. That's why a structured logging framework like Serilog is preferable - it already does this out of the box, storing data in parseable form along with the messages.

Comment: The best choice depends on what you intend to use for analyzing the log. Elastic and all log parsers have parsing templates for specific formats. Structured log formats like the [W3C Extended format used by web servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Log_Format) are both easy to read, easy to parse. There are countless tools to parse, view or query this format. The *developer* has to be disciplined enough to *specify the available fields in advance* and use that format instead of dumping unstructured messages.

Comment: The current format itself can be improved if the message field is the *only* field allowed to contain whitespace and appears last. Using tabs instead of spaces for separators would be a good idea too.